# Spring boot override application properties with CLI arg

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have `application.properties` variable for purpose of setting a default value:

```
openvasmd.socket=/usr/local/var/run/openvasmd.sock
```

I want to be able to change it during the run time of application like this:

```
java -jar -Dopenvasmd.socket=/var/run/openvasmd.sock application.jar
```

However when I want to use the value of it using:

```
@Value("${openvasmd.socket}")
private String socket;
public String test()  {
        return "gvm-cli --socketpath "+socket;
}
```

the result is:

> gvm-cli null

can anyone give me a hint where I am doing mistake?

Comment: Is the class in which you are using `@Value` marked as spring bean?

Comment: it is marked with @Component

Comment: But are you getting an instance of the class through use of `@Autowired` *(correct)*, or are you using `new` *(wrong!)*?

Comment: Do you mean that the result is `gvm-cli --socketpath null`?   It seems that you should be getting the `--socketpath` part regardless.

Comment: I'm thinking it's more an issue like what @Andreas is thinking.  If it were a question of not correctly specifying an override to the property, then you should be getting your value from `application.properties` rather than `null`. - using `new` to create your instance of the object containing this value seems like the most likely explanation.  Another explanation would be if the property were being explicitly set to `null` somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

> Properties from Command Line Arguments
>
> As opposed to using files, properties can be passed directly on the command line:

```
java -jar app.jar --property="value"
```

> You can also do this via **system properties, which are provided before the -jar command rather than after it**:

```
java -Dproperty.name="value" -jar app.jar
```

Comment: But for this to be "the answer", wouldn't it be true that he'd be getting his default value prior to this fix,  rather than `null`?

Comment: Indeed, your comments under question make a lot of sense to me. I'll leave my answer as is though, I think it still adds some insight to the discussion.